# enable remote desktop access on specific machine via domain controller

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, domaincontroller

we have a domain controller (W2008 RC2) and several computers as client machines. At the moment when we introduce a new user to the domain who has to have access to a subset of computers, the admin logs on to each of them and adds the user to the list of remote desktop users.

Is there a way to do this from the domain controller? (There has to be a way, because the way we do it sound a bit stupid, right?)

Best regards,
Sascha

Comment: What programming languages do you have at your disposal?

Comment: server side: nothing that doesn't come with w2k8 server

client side: all .net languages, php, bash (if you consider this a language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you just dont add a remote_desktop group to every computer at once. Then put the user into that group if needed. Then you control the access of the computer-access-list at the user setting "Computer Logon at/when" options.